# Start app widget on app installation in android

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I am working on app widget for my app. It is working the way I want, but I don't want that user go to widget picker & drag my app widget to home screen. This is a normal case, here I want to avoid doing this. I want when my app install than my app widget start on device homescreen.

Is it possible to do this? If yes, then please help me - I have already have done R&D but no use.

My app is based on [this](https://github.com/laaptu/appwidget-listview).

Answer (score 0):

This should not be possible. The user has to actively choose a Widget to prevent Apps from spamming the Desktop.

Comment: is it possible using App Widget Host, cant we customize the weidget property to achieve my needs